# Java hide images

Tags: java, image, timer, hide

I'm trying to make a simple program that shows that lets an image bob across the screen.
Now iv'e succeded to make an image to go form left to right but now I have like 20 images on the screen.

What I need to get is that when the next image is printed that te previous image is hidden. Also if someone could help me out with printing with a timer it would be great.

Here is my code

```
package imagemove;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class imagemove extends Component {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    BufferedImage img;

    public imagemove() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("F:/JAVA/workspace/Tutorials/src/imagemove/1.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       } 

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        x = 0;
        y = 50;

        for (int number = 1; number <= 15; number++) {
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            if (x > 1000) {
                x = 0;
            } else {
                x += 100;
            }   

            if(y > 100) {
                y -= 100;
            } else {
                y += 25;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Boot");   
        f.setSize(1000,1000);
        f.add(new imagemove());        
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works this way; it tested it:

```
public class imagemove extends Component {
    private int x;
    private int y;


    BufferedImage img;

    public imagemove() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("F:/JAVA/workspace/Tutorials/src/imagemove/1.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       } 

       x = 0;
       y = 50;
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        if (x > 1000) {
            x = 0;
        } else {
            x += 100;
        }   

    if(y > 100) {
        y -= 100;
    } else {
        y += 25;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Boot");   
    f.setSize(1000,1000);
    f.add(new imagemove());        
    f.setVisible(true);

    for (int number = 1; number <= 15; number++) {
        f.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why would `this` be an ImageObserver of the BufferedImage?

Comment: paint() should not change the state of the component. The update of x and y should be done elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

1. you should put your for-loop in another method, which is called from the main method. (the draw image instruction should remain in the paint mathod obviously)
2. use paintComponent instead of paint
3. put super.paintComponent(g) as the first line in paintComponent(). and your previous images should be cleared

Edit:

extend JComponent instead of Component. Component is AWT, JComponent is Swing

Answer (score 0):

You can't call repaint from within the paint() method.